# What's the vanilla javascript version of jQuery's $var = ($var) statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm current looking to load images that I'm grabbing from the flickr API. The plain load out is ugly, so I'm waiting till they all load and then presenting them at the same time, using the second example on [this page](http://www.barrelny.com/blog/taking-control-of-imageloading/). However that uses jQuery and I want vanilla javascript. I realize the var $img = $(img) statement is just creating an object, but it's turning a pre-existing html element into one, and I'm not sure how to do this in vanilla JS. My images look like this:

```
<img src="http://farm1.staticflickr.com/97/219568294_6a7bef5794_m.jpg" onload="loaded(this)">
```

and my function is this:

```
    function loaded(img){
        var $img = $(img);
        var total = document.getElementById('flickr').getElementsByTagName('img').length;
        var percentLoaded = null;

        $img.addClass('loaded');

        var loaded = document.getElementById('flickr').getElementsByClassName('loaded').length;

        if(loaded == total){
            percentLoaded = 100;
        } else {
            percentLoaded = loaded/total * 100;
            document.getElementById("loadingstatus").style.width = percentLoaded + "%";
        };
    };
```

Once I figure out the $ = $() part of the function I should be able to easily adding the loading class to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What `$(an HTML Element Node)` returns is not simply "an object", it is specifically a jQuery object.

The plain DOM equivalent is to just use `img` directly (and to call standard DOM methods on it instead of jQuery methods).

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense to me now. I did not know jQuery had their own objects.

Answer (score 3):

jQuery is only used here to add a class to the `img` element, so the real question is "how do I add a class to an element without using jQuery", and the answer is this:

```
img.className += " loaded";
```